# how to add asp.net web application

Tags: vb.net

I installed vb.2005. asp web application template does not come in a new project. How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to Visual Studio 2005 SP1 you should see the web application project type again and not just the web site project type.